# Click event not triggering for every iteration of for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to automate this [page](https://adarshpk.github.io/) to generate exam results. I want to generate exam results from one particular date to some other particular date. On clicking the submit button, the page generates another page in a new tab.

Manually clicking 10 times will generate 10 tabs. But see the following code:

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++)
{
document.querySelector('#reg1').click();
console.log(`clicked ${i}th time`)
}
```

I want to trigger a click 10 times and it should generate 10 tabs accordingly. But the problem is that the click works only works on the 10th iteration and spawns 1 tab only. Help me.
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRY4u.jpg)

**Edit:**
@Jesse
See my utility full code:

```
var dateFrom=new Date('2017-01')
var dateTo=new Date('2019-01')
for(var i=dateFrom;i<dateTo;i.setMonth(i.getMonth()+1))
{
    // console.log(`${i.getFullYear()}-${i.getMonth()}`);
    // var dd=`${i.getFullYear()}-${i.getMonth()}`;
    var dd=new Date(i).toISOString().substr(0,7);
    console.log(dd);
    document.querySelector("input#picker.form-control").value=dd;
    var type='Supplementary'
    document.querySelector("select#result_type.form-control.form-email.selectoption").value=type;
    document.querySelector('#reg1').click();

}
```

Comment: What is that image trying to show us?

Comment: @rayhatfield just the selector.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you have to execute the subsequence clicking in an asynchronous manner. I got this work by this:

```
let i=0;
(function doClick(){
  document.querySelector('#reg1').click();
  i++;
  if(i<10) setTimeout(() => doClick());
})()
```

Another approach using `async` function:

```
(async function doClick() {
  for(let i=0;i<10;i++) {
    document.querySelector('#reg1').click();
    await new Promise(setTimeout);
  }
})()
```

Comment: Is there any iterative way of doing this instead of recursion?

Comment: @AkhilNair I updated an `async` approach. Maybe you can say that is an iterative way?

Comment: That's awesome (y)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that my browser's popup blocker is stopping the subsequent tabs from being opened.

Try turning off your popup blocker. I was able to trigger the behavior you're after with mine off.

It works when you click it because it's a user interaction, so the blocker assumes it's something you're actively trying to do. If you trigger it programmatically, repeatedly, it gets blocked. This makes sense given that one of your browser's popup blocker's primary functions is to prevent sites from trapping you in infinite popup hell.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but no working as I expected. 

`var el2 = document.querySelector('#reg1');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => el2.click(), 5000);
console.log(`clicked ${i}th time`);
}`

This is my code. It prints 10 times, and 5 seconds later only 1 tab is spawned.

Comment: setTimeout() is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Set a breakpoint or logpoint in your click handler to see if it's getting called all 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the same ID. Either switch to using a class or change the ID names so they aren't identical.